# Как я могу запустить SDK Android 1.0 - 4.0?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk

Хочу понастальгировать и запустить версии Android с 1.0 по 4.0. В Android Studio они помечены как Deprecated и не устанавливаются на эмулятор. Есть идеи, как и где их можно запустить?

Comment: Eclipse с плагином

Comment: @Style-7 с каким именно плагином?

Comment: ADT - https://www.fandroid.info/ustanovka-eclipse-i-podklyuchenie-plagina-android-development-tools-adt-dlya-razrabotki-android-prilozhenij/